# webpack-dev-server -p .... ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs

Tags: npm, webpack, плагин, babel, wp-plugin

В package.json'е есть скрипты:

**"build": "webpack-dev-server"**,

**"build_p": "webpack-dev-server -p**"

Так вот `npm run build` - происходит нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а при `npm run build_p` - ошибка, говорящая что-то страшное про UglifyJs:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот содержимое ***package.json***:

```
{
  "name": "test123",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webpack123",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --entry ./src/js/app.js --output-filename ./dist/bundle.js",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build_p": "webpack-dev-server -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  }
}
```

содержимое ***webpack.config.js***:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MinifyPlugin = require("babel-minify-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/app.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  watch: true,

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader"},
      {test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/, query: {presets: ["es2015"]}}
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new MinifyPlugin({
      // ...
    })
  ]

};
```

Возможно это как-то связано с плагином Babel Minify, но я не очень понимаю как.

Кто что скажет?

Comment: Так а зачем вы дев сервер запускаете в продакшн режиме?

Comment: И минификация в дев режиме тоже не понятно зачем, у вас же перезагрузка проекта будет по 30 секунд занимать.

Comment: И в лоадере не `query`, а `options` у вас не работает пресет babel.

Comment: @IgorGolovin да, я вас понимаю.. просто только начинаю в этом всём копаться и пробую всё и вся.. а насчёт "query" - это из какого-то урока от горе-учителя у меня осталось.. только что сам посмотрел в документацию, там и правда "options" вместо "query".. вопрос - вы знаете нормальные ресурсы (кроме документации), по вебпаку? или только документация?

Comment: @IgorGolovin и ещё интересует вопрос по плагину.. а именно UglifyJsPlugin... у меня из-за него посыпались ошибки.. полез искать инфу через гугл.. и там многие пишут, что это проблема в этом плагине, мол пора отказываться от него.. что можете сказать на этот счёт?

Comment: По первому вебпаку есть скринкаст неплохой https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/webpack но он по версии 1, и там есть ряд отличий в настройке по сравнению с 3 версией, но в целом смысл тот же. UglifyJs сейчас один из лучших минификаторов, ошибка была скорее всего из-за того что надо было правильно подключить babel.

Comment: @IgorGolovin я смотрю, что uglifyJs не распознаёт let'ы из es2015... это так? у меня вот let people = __webpack_require__(6); в bundle.js и он на этом шаге вываливает еррор

Comment: @IgorGolovin слушай, у меня этот Uglify на отрез не хочет работать с webpack-dev-server. При этом он нормально работает просто с webpack. Вот ошибка - ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (urlParts) [bundle.js:325,4]

Comment: @IgorGolovin нашёл причину.. web-dev-server начал вываливать эту ошибку после версии 2.7.1, вот собсна issue - https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1101
... 
Решается путём автономной установки Uglify плагина и его юзанья.

Comment: uglifyJs и не должен понимать синтаксис es2015 у вас для этого есть babel. А зачем вы используете web-dev-server вместе с минификацией uglifyJs я вообще не понимаю. web-dev-server нужен исключительно для разработки приложения, а минификация для сборки для продакшена.

Comment: @IgorGolovin мне лично это ни к чему. Просто такое использование было в видеоуроке. И там оно работало. А у меня сыпятся ерроры. Вот мне и стало интересно в чём конкретно причина.

Comment: Странный урок конечно. Лучше посмотрите документацию, там минимальный рабочий конфиг занимает всего пару строк, а дольше уже добавляйте что нужно